# Is it possible to put an event handler directly to a function

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates

I have a wpf c#app.

I have an event declared in my user control and my user-control is already loaded into my main window.

In my code {somewhere appropriate) I define my event handler to a function like so:

```
    MyUserControl.MyEvent += Myfunction;
```

...

```
void Myfunction(object someData)
{
   //do something
}
```

To make things 'cleaner' i would like to do something like this instead:

```
MyUserControl.MyEvent +=> Myfunction(someData);
```

obviously, this does not compile but i put it in to try and illustrate what i want...

Comment: You could use a lambda `MyUserControl.MyEvent += (object o) => Myfunction(someData);`

Comment: that was where I was trying to get to - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a lambda for your event

```
MyUserControl.MyEvent += (object o) => Myfunction(someData);
```

The trick is that it must match the delegate signature for the event, which in your case would be a method that takes an `object` and doesn't return anything.  Note that by doing this you are ignoring the `object` that your event is sending out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Yes, I am just fiddling around with the delegate now. I have several user controls on the same page.  they each have the same event. That event calls my delegate on my main page passing in itself as the 'caller'